# VB.Net Select-Like query in MS Access not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, select, sql-like

I need to show the data from the column 'Purchaser' starting with the text entered in the textbox 'Purchaser' on the form. I am using MS Access 2003 database.
For this I am using the following...

```
            Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Purchaser] LIKE '" & Purchaser.Text & "*'"
            Dim dc = New OleDbCommand(query, cn)
            Dim rows = dc.ExecuteNonQuery
            cn.Close()

            If rows = 0 Then
                'Show a form for new entry
            Else

                Dim oleadap = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn)
                Dim dset As DataSet = Nothing
                oleadap.Fill(dset, "Details")

                For i = 0 To rows
                    Dim purName = dset.Tables("Details").Rows(i).Item("Purchaser").ToString
                    Dim purAddr = dset.Tables("Details").Rows(i).Item("Address").ToString

                    'Populate a list

                Next

            End If
```

The variable 'rows' always turns out to be zero even if I check for a Purchaser starting with, say A, in the database.

Comment: you're current code is vulnerable with `sql injection`. try searching for word that has single quote (eg. `hello's world`) and surely it will fail, use parameter instead, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Purchaser] LIKE '" _
          & Purchaser.Text & "%'"
```

In MS Access, the wild card is asterisk (*), outside of it, the wildcard is percent (%)

In addition, you have ExecuteNonQuery, but that is not true. You are executing a query, here are a few notes for testing.

```
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Purchaser] LIKE '" _
          & Purchaser.Text & "%'"
Dim dc = New OleDbCommand(query, cn)
Dim rows As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
rows = dc.ExecuteReader

If rows.HasRows Then
    Do While rows.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(rows("Purchaser"))
    Loop
End If
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Forgot to add that even '%' isn't working!
Anyways, Thanks Remou!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `%` instead of `*`. And another one, use parameter.

```
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Details WHERE [Purchaser] LIKE @purc & '%' "
Dim dc = New OleDbCommand(query, cn)
dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purc", Purchaser.Text)
Dim rows = dc.ExecuteNonQuery
```